# Disable Third party modules logging in Java application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, slf4j

I am using third party framework and our application and that framework both are having same logger `slf4j`. I have deployed my application on `Tomcat` and `IBM WAS`. Now I am seeing few severe exceptions from that framework, which I want to hide, and `only want to see the logs of my application`. Please suggest, how we could achieve it.

Comment: Configure slf4j implementation to do that.

Comment: would you please suggest some reference or snippet

Comment: How can I do that If I don't know what is your logging framework.

Comment: It should be described in the reference documentation for the logging framework that you are using.  (If you don't know what that is, check the documentation for the framework that you are using.)   Slf4j is a facade.  It doesn't do the actual logging.  Something else does ...